# Generate repeated sequence of integers while adding an offset after each repeat

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sequence, repeat

I'm trying to create a sequence of integers that repeats elements in a list a number of times while adding a constant offset to them after each repeat.

I have a pandas dataframe with many columns that are repeated blocks of information about the same `N` individuals.  For instance the columns could be [age1, age2, age3, ... ageN, height1, height2, height3, ... heightN, ... ] and I want the the columns associated with individuals 1 and 4 (for instance).  I want to generate column indices for specific individuals so I can subset the dataframe using `df.iloc[:, cindices]`.

The following code works but it's pretty ugly and I was hoping for a cleaner and clearer solution (more Pythonic).

```
subjects = [1, 4]
N = 11; repeats = 3
columns = np.array([(np.arange(repeats) * N + i) for i in subjects])
cindices = columns.T.flatten()

# Information for individuals 1 & 4 are in these columns:
>> array([ 1,  4, 12, 15, 23, 26])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the `numpythonic` version of your solution

```
(np.array(subjects)[None, :] + N*np.arange(repeats)[:, None]).ravel()
```

The `[None, :]` is not strictly necessary, but I left it in for clarity.

What's happening here is `broadcasting` if you apply a numpy-enabled operator such as `+` to arrays with shapes for example (1, 2) and (3, 1) numpy will return a (3, 2) array with the 'right' sums in the cells.

`ravel` flattens the array.

Comment: Or simply : `(subjects + N*np.arange(repeats)[:,None]).ravel()`.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I was coming to that ;-)

Comment: Up-vote to both.  Both very short solutions.  Merci.